# Upgrade Sencha Touch 1.X to Sencha Touch 2.X

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My mobile application is currently running under Sencha Touch 1.1.1.  Now, I want to upgrade it to Sencha Touch 2.0.  Can anybody help me for doing this? What general steps should I take care in while upgrading?

Also, are there tutorials that assist with the process?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here:[Upgrading to Sencha Touch 2 PR2](http://www.sencha.com/learn/upgrading-to-sencha-touch-2-pr2)

Great blog post.

Answer (score 2):

The Sencha Touch 2 docs have been updated significantly since the recent general release.  There is now an [upgrade guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/upgrade_1_to_2) and conference videos on things like the new [class system](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/class-system) and a [overview of migration from 1.x to 2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/migrating-from-1-to-2).  (Note not everything in the videos made it into the release.)  The changes are significant and not backward compatible, especially the class system, configuration, styling, packaging and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I will also try to upgrade my project. if succeed, I'll tell you about migration steps.

But in the blog of sencha told;

> As a preview release, APIs are not yet frozen. This should be fair
>   warning. Because the API is not yet frozen, we’re also not yet
>   guaranteeing backwards compatibility with Sencha Touch 1.x.
>
> Everyone attending SenchaCon later this month(I think this month is november) will also be able to
>   attend Jamie Avins’ talk on migrating apps from Sencha Touch 1 to
>   Sencha Touch 2

[Source](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-developer-preview/)